# How to increase light box width using ajax or jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a small code

```
$(".example8").colorbox({width:"50%", inline:true, href:"#inline_example1"});
```

It is ajax / jquery code for light box.  Here I have width 50%. It is ok for desktop. But in small device I need 100% width. So How to increase width for mobile ? I need to keep 50% for desktop and want to increse width for small device.

Comment: First, that is not ajax. Ajax deals with posting / getting data from a webservice. In terms of increasing the width, you would need to swap javascript files when on mobile devices, or do some sort of screen width detection and then run an if else and make the colorbox call inside of the if else

Comment: Ok thanks. I got solution from 
n1kkou (http://stackoverflow.com/users/3070830/n1kkou)

Answer (score 1):

```
var screenSize = $(window).width();
if(screenSize<500){
  $(".example8").colorbox({width:"90%"});
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. It is working but After making small change.